# SQL Simple Subtraction Query

Tags: sql, subtraction

I have a Database. It contains 2 Tables. Let me call them Table A and Table B.

**Table A Content:**

1. Date
2. Name of Supplier
3. Name of Good Delivered
4. Amount of Good Delivered, simply put Ingrediënt A (Numeric Value)

**Table B Content:**

1. Production Date
2. Name of Product
3. Ingrediënt A

**What I exactly want is:**

Query with Table A, Column 4 minus (Subtraction) Table B, Column 3.

**Extra Notes:**

I have been asking this question to a friendly programmer. He adviced me to go through the onlince course of w3schools.com which I did. He also assumed the subtraction should belong under a certain 'Join' function.

I have also been googling and searching Stackoverflow. With no results. Even tho, I need to mention that I maybe lack finding the results because my English is quite poor.

I want to sincerely apologise, if my English is poor and if my question was / is poorly phrased. English is not my native language.

If direct help is not possible, I am willing and eager to learn. If you have any sources where I can learn about simple mathematics in Querys related to Databases (Such as MS Access or OOo Base) than feel free to refer me to good and informational websites and / or courses.

Sincerely yours and with kind regards
Dofty

**System Information:**

- Windows 7 - 64 Bit - Home Edition and all it's updates
- OpenOffice.org 3.3.0 - OOO330m20(Build: 9567)

Reason for not upgrading OOo to latest version: Compatibility Issues with previous scripted software. And too 'less' time at the job to fix those issues for Version 4.0 and later.

Comment: How are those tables connected/joined, by the name of the good? Is this name unique in table A and or Table B?

Comment: I am a bit confused by GOOD, PRODUCT, INGREDIENT. Is this all the same? And one table tells me all deliveries of the product and the other all the charges, but there is no relation which charges were delivered, only which product? That looks queer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use math in SQL

```
SELECT 
    (a.column_4 - b.column_3) as subtracted_value 
FROM 
    TABLE_A as a 
JOIN 
    TABLE_B as b ON a.id = b.table_a_id
```

"subtracted_value" should be the value of column 4 of table a minus column 3 of table b here. You need to join the tables using an id so you can see which row of TABLE A belongs to which row of TABLE B.

In this example I called the id in TABLE A "id" and the pointer in TABLE B to the id of TABLE A "table_a_id".
So "id" in TABLE A and "table_a_id" in TABLE B need to be equal when they belong to the same row.

Worth taking a look at:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: This results in a full unconstrained CROSS JOIN, the OP probably didn't want this :-)

Comment: Yes sorry I have overseen this. He needs to JOIN the two tables first.

Comment: I editted my answer and I believe this should work if the OP does edit the tables to the requirements that need to be met.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to do this with a SQL query? How about something based on:
SELECT (SELECT COLUMN4 FROM tableA) - (SELECT COLUMN3 FROM tableB)

Comment: This will fail if there's more than a single row in each table :-)