# How to set a value in a database table to a value minus another value in sqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am writing a php script to edit the values in my database and I have the following line:

```
 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Child 
    SET current_points = ('$points' - '$point_value') 
    WHERE Reward.child_username = '$username' 
    AND Reward.reward_name = '$reward'");
```

This doesn't throw any errors but is not updating the database. username, points, point_value and reward are all read in  variables. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: updating child and referencing reward for where?

Comment: You should explicitly tell mysqli to throw exceptions or check for errors manually: There is no `MINUS` in mysql as far as I know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Simple Subtraction Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754596/sql-simple-subtraction-query)

Comment: When I change the MINUS to a '-' it doesn't work either

Comment: @NabinKunwar they are both seperate tables in my database

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly against the db? With some values instead of php variables? So you can check if the issue is in the query or in the values you pass to it? In the second option you need to show us the php code

Comment: Yeah this is what I am doing to test it at the minute. I have another statement above this that is using SET that is working properly so I think the problem is with the minus